# Select element from intro.js by selenium webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, intro.js

what is the correct way for me to select "Skip" button or navigate the tooltip element if I have one page that is written with intro.js, http://introjs.com/?
I have tried to use following code. but selenium webdrive return exception for overlay.

Modify the question with answer, after changing small text. no probkem for me anymore

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://introjs.com')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div//i[@id="tour-help-icon"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div//a[.="Skip"]').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

SKIP is case sensitive. Please try to change the case exactly what is there in the application. 
I am assumming,  the skip button is same as in the attached screenshot.

[image: Sample page]

The code to click on the skip the buttion is given below.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[.="Skip"]').click
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked this page http://introjs.com/. I don't see any SKIP button.

**You have given the xpath as:**

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[.="SKIP"]').click

That means there should be a link on the page with text "**SKIP**" and on clicking the link, you should be navigated to a path which should be also mentioned in the **href** attribute of the anchor tag.

It will be great if you can provide the HTML for this element.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to click **Skip** button directly. First, click the "**Demo**" button and then " **Skip**" button.

Unless you click the **Demo** button, the tooltip buttons for **Intro.js** will not be visible:

**Try this:**

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'Demo') and @class='button button-primary']").click
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[.="Skip"]').click